# Upgrading BIOS in my ASUS Vivobook R542UQ

Tags: upgrade, asus, ram, bios

I have installed a new RAM stick of 8GB in my ASUS Vivobook R542UQ-DM153 which already had an 8GB of RAM. So it's 2x8GB of RAM now. Then I noticed both my RAMs are running at 2133 speed although both of them are 2400. My current BIOS version is 202 which doesn't have an XMP profile setting. I'm thinking of upgrading the BIOS to the latest version. Please guide me on how to do so. I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Comment: I would always visit the homepage. https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1008859/  looks good. If you can do it from within BIOS that should be preferred. If it supports EZ flash all you need is the file on an USB stick.

Comment: https://www.asus.com/in/Laptops/ASUS-VivoBook-15-R542UQ/HelpDesk_Manual/

Comment: My Ubuntu is running on EFI system. Will there be an issue while upgrading BIOS?

Comment: Well... I would be more worried about the update. if the bios update fails you might brick your system. so ideal setup: power through mains, don't do up during a thunderstorm ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Some laptops will clock down the RAM speed when you add more memory.
The old laptop I'm using came with 8 GB running at 1866 MHz but when I upgraded to 32 GB it went down to 1600 MHz. That is also stated in the specifications from Dell for the model I'm using.

You might want to check the manufacture specs on your model.

I don't think updating the BIOS will make any difference. But if you still want to try, you might give this procedure a go https://www.gamersnexus.net/guides/1572-how-to-flash-bios-on-asus-board